# How to save List and return PagedResources in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

I have a List I need to return in a Spring Hateoas powered REST API as a [PagedResources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/PagedResources.html). I have tried this:

```
List<User> users = someUserGenerationMethod();
PageImpl<User> page = new PageImpl<User>(users);//users size is greater than 1
return parAssembler.toResource(page, userResourceAssembler);
```

having:

```
@Autowired
private PagedResourcesAssembler<User> parAssembler;
```

and `userResourceAssembler` is an instance of:

```
public class UserResourceAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<User, UserResource> {...}
```

and:

```
public class UserResource extends ResourceSupport{...}
```

but it results on `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page size must not be less than one!`

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Nope. I'm pretty sure your generatedUsers is empty and so is savedUser (seeing the exception). Please debug a little and provide a [mcve] and a full stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was instantiating `PageImpl`, not sure why but using a different constructor:

```
Page<User> page = new PageImpl<User>(users, new PageRequest(0, DEFAULT_USER_PAGE_SIZE), 1);
```

solved the problem. Does anybody know why? Bug or bad use?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve it.

1. Either re-query the database `repo.findAll()` to get list of users from database (this is useful in case there are some db processing involved like time-stamping or seed generation for id).
2. If no db-processing involved then I will return `generatedUsers` instead of `savedUsers`. (In this case make sure that `repo.saveAll(generatedUsers)` executed successfully and without errors).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is independent of the persistence. It occurs even with some generated list of users. I updated the question.